# How do we create dynamic url in Sharepoint 2010 Calculated field

Tags: javascript, calculated-column

I am working on creating sharepoint dashboard using color coding. I have my custom list created and all of the traffic lights are working based on condition user provides. Following is the basic set up of my list

```
Program: Single Line Text              

Light 1: Calculated Field                Light1Link: Hyperlink

Light 2: Calculated Field                Light2Link: Hyperlink

Light 3: Calculated Field                Light3Link: Hyperlink

Light 4: Calculated Field                Light4Link: Hyperlink
```

[image: Screenshot]

Now is there a way that when user clicks on those individual lights will get directed to Hyperlink provided in Light1Link, Light2Link, ... Light4Link?

Edit:

To get color coding i have been using a javascript provided in pathtosharepoint.com very close to Sharepoint user ToolKit. Jussi can you please elaborate on you idea of modifying xsl. Just a reminder i am not trying to redirect a specific or a static url. It needs to get redirected according to user input in the fields Light1Link... Light4Link. Also the traffic lights are not an image file they are html. i.e i entered following piece of html in Calculated column named Tech Lights(KPI Lights)

```
="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&[Tech]&";'>•</DIV>"
```

Which gives me Green light if Status of [Tech] column is Completed, Yellow IF [Tech} is In Progress, and Red if [Tech] is Not Started.

Comment: Please, clarify, what are you using for color coding? Conditional formatting or SharePoint User Toolkit? (http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Color-Coding-Calendar-List.aspx)

Comment: @omlin: They're using Christophe's solution (edited in from flagged answer).

Comment: Yep, thanks @StuartPegg for editing that into Octopus' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the formula you're looking for is this:

```
="<a href='"&[Link]&"'><DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&[Tech]&";'>•</DIV></a>"
```

Where `[Link]` is the name of the column containing your required link.

Comment: Stuart thank you for the help. I applied your code it gave me error "One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas."  It looks like [Hyperlink] is not supported by formulas.

Comment: @octopus: That's true. My only advice might be to copy the links into a text field.

Comment: Stuart, i tried text field instead of hyperlink, it looks nice but with one exception All of the lights are turned blue. is it because of text decoration of hyperlink. This is my html                                                        ="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&Process&";'><a href='"&[Processs Link]&"'>•</a></DIV>"

Comment: @octopus: It should display correctly if you put the link outside the div tag.

Comment: Thank You very much Stuart. One more question Instead of Html bull i decided to use Kpi LIghts from Layouts folders it worked out great. I have a custom column name prior with 3 choices in it (1) Completed (2) In Progress and (3) Not Completed                                        ="<DIV><IMG src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefaultlarge-"&(3-RIGHT(LEFT(Prior,2),1))&".gif' border='0' /></DIV>"              Now i want to add Additional Field Named (4) Not Applicable. How Do i modify above given html to fit that need.

Comment: I believe there are only 3 traffic light images, so adding a fourth options isn't really possible.

Comment: Cant we add another picture in _layouts/images/  and name it KPIDefaultlarge-4.gif.

Comment: True, you could do that. But you'd need to make sure it's on every WFE.

Comment: Yup it worked but i had to name fourth KPI light to KPIDefaultlarge--1.gif for option (4) not completed. I dont why but it worked. That should conclude this question. Now i have dashboard with kpi lights which is set according to status of a project. Users can also click on KPI lights that will forward them to designated address provided my author. Thank You very much for your help Stuart.

Comment: No worries. If this is your accepted answer, then please remember to click the tick to mark it as such.

Comment: Stuart one question relating to same discussion.  I click on those kpi lights whose links are fed from single line of text column. When the column is empty firefox doesnt do anything but IE8 is redirecting the page to site assets folder. Is there a way to stop IE from redirecting page to elsewhere when there is no content in the column.

Comment: I think you're going to have to ask that as a new question. This comment thread is already huge!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you create the dashboard, can you modify the XSL of the the dashboard and make a small change to add link tags around the traffic light picture pointing to the hyperlink defined?

Answer (score 0):

In your DIV tags (assuming that's the method you're using) creating the colors, include a unique class or ID name. Use some jQuery to grab all of your divs and wrap with a link. So following octopus example, if I take his and add a unique identifier

```
="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&[Tech]&";' class="&[Tech]&">•</DIV>"
```

And using jquery you can do something like

```
$(".Completed").wrap("<a href='url'/>")
$(".InProgress").wrap("<a href='anotherUrl'/>")
```

or if you want them all to one URL, just give it a more generic class like

```
class="myLight"
```

and then one line to wrap the link

```
$(".myLight").wrap("<a href='url'/>")
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer David. But how is $(".Completed").wrap("<a href='url'/>") is going to feed value to i.e [Light1] from column [Light1Link]. URL has to be fed from the hyperlink column where user inserts the value.

Comment: my bad, I missed the link is in the list as well... Did you try Stuart Pegg's suggestion? To get the link you could use SPServices to call the list and pull the value, or include the link column, and try using jQuery to hide the column so it's not evident. Very messy, but easier than creating a custom field.

Answer (score 0):

Found this article. It solved my problem easy, no javascript at all.

[Article](http://devdotnotes.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/sharepoint-caculated-column-and-hyperlink-no-workflow-or-script-needed/)

Make your formula i.e.

```
="<a href='"&[Link]&"'><DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&[Tech]&";'>•</DIV></a>"
```

and set "The data type returned from this formula is: " to be i.e. number. VOILA

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more flexibility, consider a computed field instead of a calculated field: http://www.threewill.com/2012/07/computed-fields-in-sp-2010/